# Pyomo: Check if solution exists and if not solve other problem

Tags: python, gurobi, pyomo

I am using pyomo with gurobi (and other solvers) to solve some optimization programs.
Sometimes these programs don't have a solution and throw an error such as

```
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model.name="unknown";
      - termination condition: infeasible
      - message from solver: Model was proven to be infeasible.
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: x[0]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0]
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: objective
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.objective.SimpleObjective'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0]

...

  File "pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx", line 246, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
  File "pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx", line 233, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0]
```

In this case, I would like to run a simpler program without some of the constraints, so something like

```
solve program
if program doesn't have a solution:
   solve simpler program
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Pyomo's website](http://www.pyomo.org/blog/2015/1/8/accessing-solver):

```
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition

…

results = opt.solve(instance) # Solving a model instance  
instance.load(results) # Loading solution into results object

if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
    # Do something when the solution in optimal and feasible
elif (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
    # Do something when model in infeasible
else:
    # Something else is wrong
    print “Solver Status: ”,  result.solver.status
```

But be careful, because you want to ensure that your simpler model doesn't return an infeasible solution too.

Comment: A solver can (1) find the optimal solution, (2) prove there is no optimal solution (infeasible or unbounded, (3) reach a time limit and find a feasible (possibly suboptimal) solution and (4) reach a time limit and not find any feasible solution.

How can we differentiate between 3 and 4?

Comment: @Chicoscience Pyomo has different solver statuses and terminations conditions and the combinations of the two, should give you what you want. Check out [this](http://www.pyomo.org/blog/2015/1/8/accessing-solver) link from their website.